# Signal r with asmx webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to implement SignalR with asmx webservice. The service is called from my front end application and my project is running.
My first question is, should I create SignalR hub here or I have to make another application for the Hub and use that for realtime purpose?

And second question is,

```
public class MyHub1: Hub
{
    public bool ConnectUser(long userId)
    {
        UserManipulation Up = new UserManipulation();//its my class to process user//
        return Up.ConnectUser(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

This is hub method to save the connection Id in database with the userid.

Now in asmx page, you know we have to create a [webmethod], so that I can call that method from front end. I want to create a webmethod which will call this hub method.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool ConnectUser(string UserId)
{
        SignalRHub.MyHub1 myhub = new SignalRHub.MyHub1();//SignalRHub is namespace//
        return myhub.ConnectUser(UserId);
}
```

But the context within the hub method getting null.

I don't know I'm in right way or not, but please help me how can I achieve the things to implement Hub not directly in front end, instead this type of service.

Comment: Why are you calling a SignalR hub method from a web method? Why don't you just directly hit the SignalR hub from JavaScript running on the client? And you really shouldn't use WebMethod. It's 2018. There's far better ways to expose an endpoint to the client side, such as Web API.

Comment: Thanks @mason. I'm just a beginner in SignalR, thats why I need expert help. I have a method for login. After login, I'm getting the userId from sql. Now I want to save connectionId with that userId in a table. So connectionId will be sent from client side or I can get in server side in that webservice?